# How to set bounds for 3d map in vtk by c++?

Tags: c++, 3d, vtk, setbounds

I have a lot of lines and planes which are around, for example, (0.5, 0.5, 0.5) point. Also I have area where they have importance, it's a cube. And lines, planes have possibility to intersect this area, and be outside of it. Can I hide part of all elements, and parts of elements, which are not included in my area? Does Vtk have opportunity to do it very simple? Or I need to do it by myself? I want to write, for example SetBounds(bounds), and after that all what isn't included in cube dissapear.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [vtkClipDataSet](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkClipDataSet.html) with the clip-function set to [vtkBox](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkBox.html). Finally, render the output from the vtkClipDataSet filter.

```
vtkNew<vtkBox> box;
box->SetBounds(.....); // set the bounds of interest.

vtkNew<vtkClipDataSet> clipper;
clipper->SetInputConnection(....); // set to your data producer
clipper->SetClipFunction(box.GetPointer());

// since clipper will produce an unstructured grid, apply the following to
// extract a  polydata from it.
vtkNew<vtkGeometryFilter> geomFilter;
geomFilter->SetInputConnection(clipper->GetOutputPort());

// now, this can be connected to the mapper.
vtkNew<vtkPolyDataMapper> mapper;
mapper->SetInputConnection(geomFilter->GetOutputPort());
```